# How to operate with character and the next character in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have a string with name, say, "John Doe", or "JohnDoe" and I want to get "John-Doe" as a result.
I can't replace " " with "-" because sometimes there's no " ". So I thought of this:

if letter is in lowercase and the next is uppercase, then input "-".

How would i do that?

Comment: Take a look at `NSRegularExpression`, if all your data follows the simple pattern of your example then you can construct a simple RE which matches first, optional space, second and then produce your first-second.